# servlet - Managing simulataneous server-push notification

Tags: java, servlets, long-polling

I am designing a very simple chat application which uses the long polling to communicate between users. I am using a servlet to store the [AsyncContexts](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) in a [Hashmap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). When userA sends a message to userB the servlet gets the corresponding AsyncContext from the HashMap and pushes the data to the client.

The code that I am using is given below-:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        if ("getAll".equals(request.getParameter("op"))) {
            String friend = request.getParameter("for");
            String jsonMessages = getChatMessagesForUser((String)request.getSession()
                    .getAttribute("id"),friend);
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println(jsonMessages);
            writer.flush();
            return;
        }

        else if ("getFrnd".equals(request.getParameter("op"))) {
            String jsonFrndList = getFriends((String)request.getSession()
                    .getAttribute("id"));
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
            writer.println(jsonFrndList);
            writer.flush();
            return;
        }

        final AsyncContext asyncContext = request.startAsync(request, response);
        asyncContext.setTimeout(30 * 60 * 1000);
        asyncContext.addListener(new AsyncListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                AsyncContext ctx = event.getAsyncContext();
                PrintWriter writer = ctx.getResponse().getWriter();
                ChatMessage directive = new ChatMessage();
                directive.setType('D');
                directive.setMessage("Keep-Alive");
                writer.println(gson.toJson(directive));
                writer.flush();
                contexts.remove(ctx);
                ctx.complete();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                AsyncContext ctx = event.getAsyncContext();
                PrintWriter writer = ctx.getResponse().getWriter();
                ChatMessage directive = new ChatMessage();
                directive.setType('D');
                directive.setMessage("Keep-Alive");
                writer.println(gson.toJson(directive));
                writer.flush();
                contexts.remove(ctx);
                ctx.complete();

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(AsyncEvent event) throws IOException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        String id = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("id");

        if(!contexts.containsKey(id)) {
            contexts.put(id, asyncContext);
        }
    }
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("application/json");
        String receiver = request.getParameter("name");
        String sender = (String) request.getSession().getAttribute("id");
        String message = request.getParameter("message");

        System.out.println(receiver + " " + message);

        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage();

        chatMessage.setType('M');
        chatMessage.setReceiver(receiver);
        chatMessage.setSender(sender);
        chatMessage.setMessage(message);
        chatMessage.setImage(false);

        if(contexts.containsKey(receiver)) {

            AsyncContext recieverContext = (AsyncContext) contexts.remove(receiver);
            System.out.println("Connections Open:" + contexts.size());
            PrintWriter writer = recieverContext.getResponse().getWriter();
            writer.println(gson.toJson(chatMessage));
            System.out.println("Message transmitted:" + 
            gson.toJson(chatMessage));
            writer.flush();
            recieverContext.complete();
        }

        try {
            System.out.println("Trying to add to database");
            ChatDAO.addToChat(chatMessage);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        }

    }
```

Let me explain what is happening-:

- User A sends the initial GET request to the servlet.
- The servlet starts an AsyncContext and adds it to the HashMap.
- User B does the same thing.
- User A sends a message to User B by posting to the servlet(doPost).
- The servlet gets the AsyncContext of user B from the hashmap. Pushes the message from User A and call complete() on it.
- User B immediately reconnects to the servlet by doing another GET (doGet).

The obvious problem of this is that when multiple people try to chat with one single person. **For example-: If User B and User C try to chat with User A a race condition arises.**

It may happen they both post a message to user A at the same time, depending on whose message is processed first the connection to user A will be closed. **And hence if a chat message arrives before the recipient reconnects the message will be discarded.**

What I need is that if the servlet is unable to find an async context for a particular user then it will wait for sometime and then after waiting if it does not still find it only then will it discard the message.

Can I write something like -:

```
synchronized(contexts) {
wait(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be better off separating the storage of messages from the async contexts so that the messages can be stored even if there is not a context for the recipient. The next time the recipient sends the get request it would find a message waiting and return it straight away.

If you are concerned about stale undelivered messages then you could have a single thread that checks periodically for messages over a certain age and returns them to the sender. It could also just destroy old return to sender messages

Comment: Can you name a data structure that I can use ? HasMaps store one value for one key. What I would need is multiple values to one key. Any java collections utility that can do that ?

Comment: You could use `HashMap<User, ArrayList <Message>>` how might need some synchronization around the add/remove of messages but that is a different issue.